# Why windows workflow runtime is creating two instances of my workflow?

Tags: workflow-foundation, workflow-activity

While debugging production code - I observed that my workflow constructor was triggered multiple times. I do not wanted to blame WWF readily for that because of philosopy - 'check your code before blaming others'. I created a sample application to test that aspect and found that two worklow instances are getting created. Ideally only one instance should have been created. Curious to understand - why WWF runtime is creating two instances?

Code listing:

```
public partial class TestWorkflow : SequentialWorkflowActivity
{
    public TestWorkflow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        countOfInstances++;
    }

    protected override ActivityExecutionStatus Execute(ActivityExecutionContext executionContext)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Instances Created = {0}", countOfInstances);
        return base.Execute(executionContext);
    }

    private static int countOfInstances = 0;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WF3 in many cases cloned activites to do work.  It could be that is why this is happening.  WF4 does not not do this as one of the many improvments and performance optimizations in WF4.

Comment: Glad to see a response from someone who I admire a lot. I am a fan of your channel9 show. I would appreciate If you can look at one more WWF query from me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698501/weird-issue-with-window-workflow-foundation-activity-binding-does-not-seem-to